# Change database of a ColdFusion website

Tags: sql, coldfusion, cfml

I'm newbie in ColdFusion. 
I have a running ColdFusion website I'd like to update. I've copy the database to make some test, in the ColdFusion manager I have created a new datasource with the copied database. But now how can I tell my website that it need to use the copied database?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you have a test database, you probably want to use conditional logic to determine which one to use.  Here is an example from one of my files.

```
<cfscript>
    if (cgi.path_info contains "dwtest") {
    dsn = "AntibioticsTest";
    } else {
    dsn = "Antibiotics";
}
</cfscript>

<cfquery name="GetLastInsertDates" datasource="#dsn#">
sql not relevent
</cfquery>
```

As mentioned in jhinkley's answer, this variable might be a global variable in which case it's most likely found in Application.cfc.

Comment: Thanx a lot! Indeed I was looking for that file Application.cfm

Comment: @blop the file may be called Application.cfc (notice the file extension)

Answer (score 3):

Look in your code and find any `cfquery` tags and make sure they are using the new dsn in the `datasource` attribute.  Depending on how the code is written, there may be a global variable that holds the dsn and you can just change it there.